# 2D array as input in Tensorflow android

Tags: android, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-lite

I collect data from the sensors accelerometer and gyroscope in a 2D double array (128 rows, 6 columns) and I want to use it as input in Android tensorflow model. I have a pre-trained CNN model. The format of the CNN's file is ".pb" and I can't understand how to feed my CNN with 2D array.

If anyone can help me, I will appreciate.